# Как добавить роль «Роль по работе с БУС»?

Tags: 1с

В руководстве по установке модуля обмена 1С + Интернет магазин, в последнем пункте, написано:

> "После установки модуля, для работы с ним, пользователям необходимо добавить роль «Роль по работе с БУС»."

Где находится данная настройка, как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Если модуль вшитый в 1С, тогда

Администрирование (верхнее меню) ⇒ Пользователи ⇒ Выбираете пользователя ⇒ Жмакаете на 2ю вкладку "Прочие" ⇒ Ставите галочку на нужную роль.